# Postgres Query to find whether database is read-only mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am new to postgres. In mysql we can check whether the database is in read-only mode by triggering the below query.

SELECT @@global.read_only

Likewise can anyone pls help me with the query to do the same in postgres? I tried few things like below

```
SELECT schemaname||'.'||tablename FROM pg_tables
WHERE
  has_table_privilege ( 'postgres', schemaname||'.'||tablename, 'select' )
  AND schemaname NOT IN ( 'pg_catalog','information_schema');
```

But it is listing like below which I am not expecting.

```
         ?column?                
----------------------------------------
 public.schema_migrations
 public.credential_methods
 public.notifications
 public.site_defaults
 public.apis
 public.client_applications
 public.api_groups
 public.operations
 public.client_application_labels
 public.client_application_label_values
 public.roles
 public.users
 public.sdm_user_roles
 public.permissions_roles
 public.keys
 public.o_two_access_tokens
 public.settings
 public.sdm_users
 public.permissions
 public.audits
 public.oauth_requesttokens
 public.oauth_access_tokens
 public.oauth_verifiers
 public.logged_exceptions
 public.api_call_details
 public.api_access_roles
 public.api_access_users
 public.login_attempts
 public.system_scopes
 public.keys_system_scopes
 public.o_two_auth_codes
 public.o_two_refresh_tokens
 public.service_profiles
 public.error_traces
```

I also tried "\du" but this one is working only in terminal but not from a ruby file.

```
query=ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("\du;")
```

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "du"
LINE 1: du;

Thanks,
Rafiu

Comment: The backslash-commands  (like `\du` ) are not part of SQL but are terminal-monitor commands for the psql commandline front-end. For your original question: I don't know the answer. Just try to insert or update, and handle the error.

Comment: I don't think there is a "read-only" database concept in PostgreSQL. Additionally: *But it is listing me something which I am not expecting*. So you should show us what you get **and** what you are expecting.

Comment: Hey thanks for your response. I am getting the below output when I trigger the query

Comment: And what **would** you expect? The output is all tables where the user `postgres` has the `select` privilege. As the `postgres` user is usually the "super user" this output is not really surprising.

Answer (score 11):

If you have a multi-node instance cluster, and you have the hot standby configuration. The output of `SELECT pg_is_in_recovery()` can tell you if the cluster is in the read-only mode.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want something of the `has_*_privilege()` family function for *relevant tables* and *relevant privileges*. See [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-info.html). Other than that I'm not sure if postgres has a concept of read-only mode.

Well, there's also `show transaction_read_only` inside a read-only transaction, but that doesn't seem to be like what you're asking for. And I don't think that transaction being readonly affects *privileges* of the user.

I'm not sure what you expect from your query, but if you want something boolean, as in whether you have access anywhere, you can use `count(*)!=0` (and, probably, not `select`).

Comment: My DBA tells me that PostgreSQL does have a read-only mode.  In my organization, our PostgreSQL clusters are configured with an A server (r/w) and a read-only B server that's in "[hot standby](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/hot-standby.html)" mode.  Changes made to A replicate to B.  The B server accepts connections, but gives an error if you try to make a change.  The docs say "All such connections are strictly read-only; not even temporary tables may be written."  To determine if you accidentally connected to the B server, our DBA recommends `show transaction_read_only`.

Comment: @DavidCostanzo, I *think* your DBA is right, though I'm a bit behind with postgres' replication and stuff, I also *think*, though that my answer was pretty correct for the valentine's day of 2012 ;-)

If I knew more I would update it, but I need to get myself up to date first, so let's hope people read these comments and do the homework themselves ;-)