# ERROR: cannot execute UPDATE in a read-only transaction in IntelliJ IDEA with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, intellij-idea

I'm connecting to the PostgreSQL database using IntelliJ IDEA DB Navigator plugin. Connections is established, and I can do selects on different tables. But when I try to execute an update statement from the console, I get the following error:

[image]

```
Error executing UPDATE statement. ERROR: cannot execute UPDATE in a read-only transaction - Connection: *: 47ms
```

Is there any way to figure out how to fix the error or how to check why the transaction in the read-only mode?

Versions: IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.2 (Ultimate Edition)
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
DB Navigator version 3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I ended up connecting to the read-only slave replica instead of the master database.  We used multiple-host connection string in the form of

```
postgresql://host1:port1,host2:port2,host3:port3/
```

where one of the hosts was a slave replica.  Without setting `targetServerType=master` the JDBC connected to the read-only replica.

After checking that the instance is indeed [in recovery mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28642060/5681468),  [or read-only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9277406/5681468), I changed the connection string. Adding `targetServerType=master` (or `targetServerType=primary`) settings resolved the issue:

```
jdbc:postgresql://hostmaster.com:5432,hostsecond.com:5432/dbName?&targetServerType=master
```